# asp.net: Scan Documents from Scanner using and upload it to web app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been asked to create a button called "Scan". When this button is clicked, it will start scanning the file in the Scanner machine and then Upload it to the server from my asp.net web application. However, I've searched throughout many websites and I found out that there must be a third-party to do that. Is there any scanning service or some script that can be integrated to perform this task?

Comment: Techincally it is possible only if your browser support it, natively I never see any browser by default support it, so you have to install browser plugin or something. You can try Silverlight like stuff to try, but, it won't worth the cost, Better show a popup on instructing user to scan document save and than upload it from upload feature on your site.

Comment: i know it is possible using Java Applets but i want to know how to do that in .net

Comment: Java Applets stop them in same manner as ActiveX Controls in past, or XPI extension for Firefox. in nutshell, you need to extend the browser with 3rd party extension to get it supported. You can try Silverlight or Flash maybe they already do it for you.

Comment: I am also in search for such feature for my ASP.NET web app. Thank You to put this question.

Comment: It *was* possible with Java applets once upon a time. But good luck running one of those today. That kind of thing was deemed insecure and dangerous, and you'll increasingly find those features are disabled.